# Why can you accept your own answer to your question?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I was reviewing questions that I asked and wanted to accept an answer which I then saw was actually supplied by me (yes, I answered my own question) - [The “Shir Hamaalos” etc before Maariv: is it said before nightfall?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18560/the-shir-hamaalos-etc-before-maariv-is-it-said-before-nightfall)

I tried - the system accepted it. I then reversed it as it seems open to abuse.

What is the official view?

Comment: See [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/why-cant-i-accept-my-own-answer/) and [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/)

Comment: @Michoel Thank you

Comment: @Michoel, why don't you post a quick summary of the latter source as an answer?

Comment: This would be a great opportunity to demonstrate the value of a self-answer. :-)  Another source: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/307/472

Comment: [status-bydesign]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Accepting your own answer is an [intentional](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) feature in the StackExchange network. By accepting an answer you make it clear that the question has been resolved, and easy to see the accepted which is marked with a green check-mark. Usually accepting an answer gives 15 reputation points to the answerer, and permanently docks the answer directly under the question irrespective of up-votes, however this is not the case if you accept your own answer which is why this cannot be abused. Additionally, you are not able to accept your own answer within 48 hours of asking the question.